# TV Movie about robot theme park with noir setting

Tags: story-identification

This was on the sci-fi channel in the mid-late 90's- people release their aggression by brutalizing androids in a theme park- sounds like Westworld but instead of being designed to simulate the wild west it had a film noir setting- private eyes, gangsters and the like. There are a few things I do remember if they help narrow it down:

1. One of the androids (the film had a nickname for them but I don't recall it) was played by Jerry Doyle, most widely known as Garibaldi from Babylon 5; a scientist running the park was played by Empty Nest star David Leisure.
2. One scene where just before an android is about to be either destroyed or recycled, a sadistic worker saying "You're smoke now" (possibly smoked).
3. near the end the AI running the place is somehow induced to self-destruct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [*The Outsider*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0139515/)

This movie was apparently also called *Gangster World*, but is unrelated to the much more famous [*Westworld*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westworld)

[image]

According to the IMDB description:

> In a futuristic **theme park**, people interact with androids in **mafia
>   gangster scenarios**, unleashing their deepest violent and sexual
>   desires on the android characters.

The [cast list](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0139515/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) does show Jerry Doyle, playing a character named Rains.